# Manually loading navigation properties in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

What is the best way to manually load navigation property in MVC 6?

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Reservation reservation, bool ignoreConflicts = false)
{
    int id = reservation.ItemID;  // correct item ID
    Item item = reservation.Item; // null
}
```

In this example, when user submits a form, I get a Reservation object with all navigation properties set to null.

The best way I can think of is manually looking up the Item DbSet to find the item with matching ID and assigning it to the navigation property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first thing first... you are in an MVC action. What you will receive will be from the client. Not the database directly.

So `reservation.Item` might not be null but it might not be the real data either.

In this scenario, you first have to retrieve your data from the server and then do one of two things:

1. Update the EF7 entity directly by hand from what you received from the client
2. Use `TryUpdateModelAsync` to update your current entity automatically.

It could be as simple as:

```cs
public ActionResult Update(Reservation reservation)
{
    var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == reservation.ItemID);
    await TryUpdateModelAsync(item);
    // todo: save context
    // return....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an Entity Framework 7 issue, not an MVC6 one.
Lazy loading isn't implemented for EF7 yet, possibly it won't be at all.

You can track the ticket here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797

This means instead we need to do it as you suggested; something like:

`Item item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == reservation.ItemID);`

Comment: My question is about explicit loading. What you suggested will work, but looks results in problems when you save the changes to the DB.